# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem and the complexity of arithmetic

Tags: peano-arithmetic, nt.number-theory, lo.logic

In [*How complicated can structures be?*](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/people/jouko.vaananen/How_complicated.pdf) Jouko Väänänen says:

> *The guiding result of mathematical logic is the Incompleteness Theorem of Gödel,
>   which says that the logical structure of number theory is so complicated that it cannot be
>   effectively axiomatized in its entirety. In other
>   words, the theory is non-recursive, i.e. there
>   is no Turing machine that could tell whether
>   a sentence of number theory is true or not.*

I've never seen Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem this way: that it's a matter of the overall *complexity* of the structure of the natural numbers that there are facts about them that cannot be proved.

So I wonder whether I can take the quote above literally:

> Can Gödel's Theorem be rigorously stated in terms
>   of complexity?

Somehow like this: "Every
system which exceeds complexity
threshold X is undecidable."

Or is it just a vague paraphrase, not to be taken too seriously?

Comment: Your main question "Can Godel ....in terms of complexity" is somewhat ambiguous: because the term complexity might be construed here either as *logical* (or quantifier) complexity, or as *computational* complexity. In the former case, as J.D. Hamkins showed, the answer to your question is "yes". In the latter case, I would presume the answer might be "no". (On the other hand, Godel's incompleteness phenomenon does hold for weak theories (bounded arithmetic), which have formal relations with computational complexity classes.)

Comment: What kind of complexity does Väänänen mean, one might ask? (Might it be case that he has in mind a more abstract concept of complexity?)

Comment: I presume Väänänen meant *computational* complexity, that is, computability?  In fact, it's hard for me to imagine an interesting formulation of Godel's incompleteness that doesn't involve computability: you could just say that PA is incomplete, but that seems too localized to be interesting; or there's the cocktail-party version that "arithmetic can't be axiomatized" which, taken literally, is false (just take the set of all sentences true in the structure (N, +, times)).

Comment: There are several meanings of complexity here. One is computational complexity, e.g. polynomial-time computation. Another is the sort of complexity measured by the arithmetical hierarchy. A third is the internal combinatorial structure of a particular model. In this informal third sense, dense linear orders have little complexity, while nonstandard models of PA have great complexity. In the quote above, I think the third sense is being alluded to. However, Väänänen does mention computational complexity in the context of finite models later in his paper. 

Answer (score 30):

Yes, this line of thought is perfectly fine.

A set is decidable if and only if it has complexity
$\Delta_1$ in the [arithmetic
hiearchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy),
which provides a way to measure the complexity of a
definable set in terms of the complexity of its defining
formulas. In particular, a set is decidable when both it
and its complement can be characterized by an existential
statement $\exists n\ \varphi(x,n)$, where $\varphi$ has
only bounded quantifiers.

Thus, if you have a mathematical structure whose set of
truths exceeds this level of complexity, then the theory
cannot be decidable.

To show that the true theory of arithmetic has this level
of complexity amounts to showing that the arithmetic
hierarchy does not collapse. For every $n$, there are sets
of complexity $\Sigma_n$ not arising earlier in the
hierarchy. This follows inductively, starting with a
universal $\Sigma_1$ set.

[Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of
truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)
goes somewhat beyond the statement you quote, since he
shows that the collection of true statements of arithmetic
is not only undecidable, but is not even definable---it
does not appear at any finite level of the arithmetic
hiearchy.

Finally, it may be worth remarking on the fact that there
are two distinct uses of the word *undecidable* in this
context. On the one hand, an assertion $\sigma$ is not
decided by a theory $T$, if $T$ neither proves nor refutes
$\sigma$. On the other hand, a set of numbers (or strings,
or statements, etc.) is undecidable, if there is no Turing
machine program that correctly computes membership in the
set. The connection between the two notions is that if a
(computably axiomatizable) theory $T$ is complete, then its
set of theorems is decidable, since given any statement
$\sigma$, we can search for a proof of $\sigma$ or a proof
of $\neg\sigma$, and eventually we will find one or the
other. Another way to say this is that every computably
axiomatization of arithmetic must have an undecidable
sentence, for otherwise arithmetic truth would be
decidable, which is impossible by the halting problem (or
because the arithmetic hierarchy does not collapse, or any
number of other ways).

Answer (score 7):

I agree with your statement
"Every system which exceeds complexity threshold X is undecidable".

Let us focus on the specific case where we consider the the first order theory of a fixed
structure.
Once the structure is complicated enough to simulate (or to express) computation,
the theory becomes undecidable.

This is based on the following easy proof of a weak form of the incompleteness theorem:
In the language of number theory, you can write down a formula $\varphi(x)$
such that the natural numbers satisfy $\varphi(t_n)$ for a natural number $n$ iff
$n$ is the Goedel number of a Turing machine that halts on an empty tape.
Here $t_n$ denotes the term for the $n$-th successor of $0$.
If the theory of the natural numbers was decidable, then you could decide the halting 
problem.

Comment: How could "simulate (or express) computation" be defined rigorously?

Comment: One rigorous definition would be the following
(I know that this looks almost silly, but this is a general criterion that I can come up with):

There is a computable function $f$ assigning to each natural number
(or description of a Turing machine, if you wish) $n$ a sentence $\psi_n$ in the language of the structure such that the structure satisfies $\psi_n$ iff the Turing machine with Goedel number $n$ 
halts on the empty tape.  

Such a function exists in case of the natural numbers, namely, let 
$\psi_n=\varphi(t_n)$.

Comment: Comment continued:  In order to prove the existence of a function
$n\mapsto\psi_n$ you would usually need to show that you can actually
"simulate" computation in your structure in one way or other.

Comment: When we consider the natural numbers as an infinite directed graph, what are the properties of this graph, that enable it to simulate computation, and that other infinite graphs do not have? What are its sufficient and what are its necessary properties? (Infinitely many distinguishable (=adressable) nodes?)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, nobody has mentioned [Chaitin's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Chaitin%27s_incompleteness_theorem).

Comment: Nice and very relevant point — but could you say at least a little more here, so that this isn’t just a link-only answer?

Comment: @Peter, the user you are addressing has not been seen here since March 2012.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: oops, I’d misread the “edited” date as the “answered” date and thought this was new…