# What is known about stability of number theoretic statements for Beurling systems which are based on small perturbations of the ordinary primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Beurling considered a sequence of reals $1<x_1<x_2<\cdots <$ as "primes" and then the ordered sequence of all products of these "primes" as "integers". Let us consider Beurling primes which are small perturbations of the ordinary primes. My question is:

1) How small perturbation guarantees that the Beurling primes/integers satisfy the prime number theorem.

2) How small perturbation guarantees that the system of Beurling primes/integers satisfies the RH given the "ordinary" RH.

3) How small perturbation guarantees that the the system of Beurling primes/integers satisfies Cramér's conjecture ("the number of integers between the $n$th prime ($p_n$) and the $n+1$ prime is $O(\log^2 p_n)$) given the "ordonary Cramér's conjecture".

**Remark:** I left the notion "small perturbation" vague and there is some other vagueness in the questions. But I will be interested in answers for any variant. Other basic results/conjectures can also be considered, and I will be interested also in information about them.

**Motivation:** This is motivated by some questions raised during the discussion of polymath 4 that I recalled in the context of the recent question [The enigmatic complexity of number theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282869/1532) .

**Clarification:** (In response to Lucia.) I am looking for results of the following kind. (1) If $x_n=p_n+f(n)$ then the Beurling system based on $x_n$ satisfies the PNT. (2) If $x_n=p_n+g(n)$ then assuming RH, the Beurling system based on $x_n$ satisfies the assertion of the RH. (3)If $x_n=p_n+h(n)$ then assuming Cramér's conjecture, the Beurling system based on $x_n$ satisfies the assertion of Cramér conjecture.

Comment: Hi Gil, I don't really know what you're after, but have you looked at this paper of Diamond, Vorhauer and Montgomery already? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-005-0638-2

Comment: Dear Lucia, thanks, references and brief simple nontechnical description of results of this kind is what I am mainly after. I suppose Beurling's original paper can be seen and turned into an answer for 1) (maybe there are better results) and the paper you mentioned is close in spirit to 2).

Comment: @Lucia , I added further clarification.